# Insert multiple rows from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

How can I insert multiple rows from another table with multiple rows without using a cursor?

Example:

Let's say I have three tables:

1. `Customers` (`CustomerId`, `Name`)
2. `Gifts` (`GifId`, `GiftName`)
3. `GiftsToCustomers` (`GiftId`, `CustomerId`)

The table customers and gifts can contain more then one row.

Now let's say I have 3 gifts in the table `Gifts` and I want to give this to all my customers.

Is there a way I can do this without using an cursor/loop through either the `Customers` or `Gifts` table?

I'm not looking for something like

```
insert into GiftsToCustomers 
    Select GiftId, @CustomerId 
    from Gifts
```

Where I have to do it on every row in customers/gifts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cross join should do the trick - you can use it to match each row in `gifts` with each row in `custmers`:

```
INSERT INTO GiftsToCustomers (GiftId, CustomerId)
SELECT      GiftId, CustomerId
FROM        Gifts
CROSS JOIN  Customers
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for. I know it had to be some better way than using cursors.